# ODE solver using Lobatto IIIA with table of coefficients

Tags: matlab, ode, runge-kutta

So I'm trying to figure out how to solve a given equation **y'=-y+2te^(-t+2)** for t in [0,10], step of 0.01 and y(0)=0.

I am supposed to solve it using the Lobatto IIIA method following a Butcher tableau:

[Coefficients table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvuEi.png)

So far, this is what I got:

```
function lob = Lobatto_solver()
     h = 0.01;
     t = 0:h:10;
     y = zeros(size(t));
     y(1) = 0;

     f = @(t,y) -y + (2*t*(exp(-t+2)));

     % Lobatto IIIA Method
     for i=1:numel(y)-1
         f1 = f(t(i), y(i));
         f2 = f(t(i)+(1/2)*h, y(i) + (5/24)*h*f1 + (1/3)*h*f2 + (-1/24)*h*f3);
         f3 = f(t(i)+h, y(i) + (1/6)*h*f1 + (2/3)*h*f2 + (1/6)*h*f3);
         y(x) = y(i) + h*((-1/2)*f1 + (2)*f2 + (-1/2)*f3);
     end
 end
```

It obviously makes no sense from the point when I equal f2 to itself, when the variable is still undefined.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: You will need a predictor-corrector loop or apply Newton's or a similar method to solve the implicit equations.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a predictor-corrector loop, in the simple case the corrector uses the slope-equations as basis of a fixed-point iteration. In the code below I use also the value of an explicit Euler step, in principle you could initialize all slopes with `f1`.

```
function lob = Lobatto_solver()
    h = 0.01;
    t = 0:h:10;
    y = zeros(size(t));
    y(1) = 0;

    f = @(t,y) -y + (2*t*(exp(-t+2)));

    % Lobatto IIIA Method
    for i=1:numel(y)-1
        f1 = f(t(i), y(i));
        f3 = f(t(i)+h, y(i)+h*f1)
        f2 = (f1+f3)/2;
        for k=1:3
          f2 = f(t(i)+(1/2)*h, y(i) + (5/24)*h*f1 + (1/3)*h*f2 + (-1/24)*h*f3);
          f3 = f(t(i)+h, y(i) + (1/6)*h*f1 + (2/3)*h*f2 + (1/6)*h*f3);
        end;
        y(i+1) = y(i) + h*((-1/2)*f1 + (2)*f2 + (-1/2)*f3);
    end
    plot(t,y,t,0.05+t.^2.*exp(-t+2))
end
```

The graph shows that the result (blue) is qualitatively correct, the exact solution curve (green) is shifted so that two distinct curves can be seen.
[image]